# Exclusion criteria for calculated measure using date

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I am working on a PowerPivot report that has the following tables/relationships:

FactTable:

- Client
- Issue
- DateID

DimDate

- DateID
- Year
- Quarter
- Month

I wish to create a calculated measure that is COUNT(Issue)/DISTINCT(Client) by Year and Quarter and that is filtered to exclude clients who only had 1 issue per quarter from the calculation.

The first part of this is straightforward enough by creating two calculated measures:
[Distinct Client] = COUNTROWS(DISTINCT('FactTable'[Client]))
[Issues per Client] = 'FactTable'[Count of Issue]/'FactTable'[Distinct Client]

Pivot:
Row Labels = Year, Quarter
Values = [Issues per Client]

I'm just learning DAX so I'm not sure how to put go about this.  It seems that CALCULATE() or CALCULATETABLE() are my best bets, but I don't know how to use it to filter on [Issues per Client per Quarter].  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found to do this is to add Client as a Row Label and [Count of Issues] to Values then create a value filter for Client where [Count of Issues] is greater than 1.

Final output looks something like this with Quarter collapsed:

Year | Quarter | Client --- Count of Issue | Cases Per Client